# XML attribute reading in java

Tags: java, xml, solr

I was struggle to read the XML coming from solr result in JAVA, now I use document and node list for parsing XML, I need to read the every value of node and I need to read the last value of eventID. This is my XML Result from Solr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">338</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
<doc>
<long name="ID">4</long>
<int name="SourceID">2</int>
<str name="SourceTitle">EIT</str>
<str name="SourceDescription">ethichal intelligent technologies</str>
<str name="Active">1</str>
<date name="CreateDate">2006-01-17T00:00:00Z</date>
<str name="_version_">1436370186807541760</str></doc>
<doc>
<long name="ID">5</long>
<int name="SourceID">2</int>
<str name="SourceTitle">EIT</str>
<str name="SourceDescription">ethichal intelligent technologies</str>
<str name="Active">1</str>
<date name="CreateDate">2006-01-17T00:00:00Z</date>
<str name="_version_">1436370268221079552</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

In this I have to read SourceID, SourceTitle and need to read the last attribute of SourceDescription.
Please help me,how to get the value of SourceID (that mean 2),SourceTiltle value (That mean EIT) like that..

Comment: SourceDescription doesn't have an attribute, so what are you trying to read? What is the problem you're currently having with your code -- i.e. we can help you debug your code to figure out the problem. Also, is there a reason why you're not using something like SolrJ?

Comment: what hv u tried so far?

Comment: In this particular line <int name="SourceID">2</int>, how to read the value,i mean attribute as SourceID,i am not using solrj,i got the XML but i don't know how to extract the XML

Comment: "i don't know how to extract the XML" --> for small XML files you can use DOM. Otherwise try the SAX or StaX APIs. Edit: this is a bit reductive but I'm oversimplifying here for lack of direction.

Comment: i am using this file to read the XML                            org.w3c.dom.Document;
 org.w3c.dom.Element;
 org.w3c.dom.Node;
org.w3c.dom.NodeList;                                                   My question is how to read the SourcID value from the above XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the value "SourceID":

```
Element el = (get to the element named int);
String value = el.getAttribute("name");
// value should equals "SourceID"
```

If what you really wanted was the number 2, use:

```
String content = el.getTextContent();
// and then convert to integer, or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer,still i struggle with this,Is there possible to get the value by like ID,SourceID,SourceDescription,kindly give me a step by step process,

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking... if you're asking "get the value of SourceID where ID = <some value>, you'll want to look up using XPath, which is the correct way to do that (and better to read a brief tutorial than trying to explain here).